# Wordpress comments for my custom table of records

Tags: wordpress, records

I need some advice on if I did it right or if I should implement the whole thing differently.

I am writing some custom code for wordpress so the users can add information regarding their dance classes.

For example one user can post that on Friday night had a dance class and upload a photo and write some details.

The records are kept on separate tables which I created already.

The whole system works good (I think) and users can add their classes, update or delete them.

What I am trying to figure out is how can I make it possible for the other users to make comments.

Is there any way to somehow connect the commenting system, the wordpress already has, to my records? Or I should had my records be assigned to a post (each dance class to a different post)?

Can you give any link or info?

---

I have edited it because the comment could not fit my answer.

Thank you very much for your reply! It took me so long to reply because of my work and I also wanted to try first what you suggested.

I did a couple of tests and everything seems to work almost as I would like to (I followed a nice tutorial about movie reviews).

The one issue I have is that I cannot figure out how I could use relational data (not sure if I said it right..). What I mean is normally I need to have more than one tables where I store several kinds of stuff..

For example I said I followed a tutorial about movie reviews..

In the tutorial it was assumed that each movie will have..

- Title
- Director
- Rating
- Plot

It seems to be straightforward because in the loop it fetches all the needed data based on the custom post id.

What happens if the movie directors are more than one? How can I have all of them related to the movie?

I was used in working with several tables like that..

Movie_Table
Director_Table
Movie_Director_Table

Where as you understand you have movies, directors and one tables with foreign keys to link the other two.

One solution so far for the custom posts would be to store in the director field the ids of the directors instead of the director name and query the details separately..

Or is it better to create a different custom post type for movies and a different for directors? And connect them somehow?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this a perfect case for custom post types. It stores the posts that your users create in the wp_posts table (within WordPress), and allows the WordPress comments to interact with the posts without much work.

Also, you can extend custom post types with the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin, by adding additional data to store with the post.

Read more about [custom post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) on the Codex.

Comment: Thanks Michael!
I have edited my post since the comments could not fit my answer!

Comment: My recommendation would be to build a single custom post type, then use Advanced Custom Fields to add any and all necessary fields you need to have, that way you are working inside of WordPress and not outside of WordPress.

Comment: Hello again!

I was thinking something like that..

To create a custom post type.. just to differentiate my posts from the regular ones and of course take advantage of the commenting system.

Then, I can simply use the add_action( 'save_post', 'populate_other_tables'); with my own function to populate data to other tables outside wordpress.

How does this sound?

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to use tables outside of the standard WordPress tables.